# How to extract timestamp from filenames in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have 10 hourly files with names: ``` file_2018-01-01_01_temp.tif``file_2018-01-01_02_temp.tif ```... `file_2018-01-01_10_temp.tif`. I want to create a timestamp in pandas:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

filenames = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('/abc/Jupyter_Works_2/1/*.tif')]
aa = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H').strftime('%Y%m%d%H')
pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(aa)])
```

It shows `TypeError: Cannot convert input [Index(['2018010101', '2018010102'....... of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> to Timestamp`.

Comment: What is reason cannot be used `aa = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H')` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, with that, I also get `Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 01:00:00' ....... of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need array of timestamps in pandas is created `DatetimeIndex`:

```
d = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H')
print (d)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2018-01-01 02:00:00',
               '2018-01-01 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If need python datetimes:

```
d = pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H').to_pydatetime()
print (d)
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 1, 0) datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 2, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 3, 0)]
```

Or list of `Timestamps`:

```
d=[pd.Timestamp(x) for x in pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H')]
print (d)
[Timestamp('2018-01-01 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-01 02:00:00'), 
 Timestamp('2018-01-01 03:00:00')]
```

Comment: With use of first code for many files, there is not sorted times in result.

Comment: @nickan - How working `pd.to_datetime([f[5:18] for f in filenames], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H').sort_values()` ?

Comment: That's great job :)